# Question marks instead of libre office icons

Tags: 18.04, unity

Hi with the update of libre office to the current version if I open Base and Impress they appear on the launcer of question marks as icons. Can I fix this bug?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the snap version or the PPA version? Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: PPA version of course...

Comment: Provide detail on your Ubuntu version and Libreoffice version. Is this the default version that comes with Ubuntu or is it from a different PPA? Use "Edit" to add any info directly to your question.

Comment: Then I use Ubuntu 18.04 lts with unity desktop. The Libre Office version is 7.1

Comment: I still haven't found a comment that can help me. Can you do it? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the question mark for *Select a template* window. It is shown on my fresh 18.04 LTS VM with Unity using default icon theme and fully installed LibreOffice from PPA by `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`. Moreover on MATE *Select a template* window is shown on *Window List* applet as non-LibreOffice icon too.

| Unity | MATE |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Unity] | [image: MATE] |

Using older LibreOffice 6.0.7 from official Ubuntu repositories solves this issue, but older LO is less functional and old.

So I think that it is not a bug of Unity or MATE.
Really LO 7.1 uses wrong icon for the Template wizards.
I have reported it to launchpad as [bug 1936966](https://pad.lv/1936966), you can subscribe to it.

Comment: Hello. I thank you again for your help. Since I am new I will subscribe to the suggested tread. And we hope that the fix comes right away. Thanks again Francesco

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, you can accept it by clicking on the check at the left.